# Control output of XL6009 Boost converter with Arduino

Tags: pwm

I wonder if someone could help me with figuring out how to control XL6009 Boost converter via Arduino. I have [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LP2LZ4M) popular board, and it has potentiometer to adjust the output voltage. However, I want to adjust output voltage based on sensor reading so I need to do it "non-mechanically".

I tried with PWM voltage to the resistor network, but I didn't get wanted results. Any ideas (except digipot)?

Best regards

Comment: you posted your question in the wrong place ... this site is for questions about the Arduino

Comment: `I didn't get wanted results` is meaningless ... it does not describe the observed behavior

Comment: And why are you excluding digipots? Most Arduinos don't have a DAC, so you would need extra parts anyway

Comment: injecting a buffered (low pass, unity gain) voltage into the wiper of the pot didn't work? It works for me. You might not have enough current being injected. No more than a 1k resistor between opamp and wiper. You can also PWM+smooth to feed an optoisolator (or CDS varistor glued to an LED) that call pull one half of the pot down/up. Digipots won't work here, don't even bother.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. When I said I didnt get wanted results with resistor network, voltage range to control was too narrow (e.g 22-24V). But here is useful guide https://www.fischl.de/dcdccontrol/. When I changed resistor values a bit, it worked as intended